# changing style of loaded iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using an iframe as a kind of lightbox container and I need to change the style of the contents of the iframe after it is loaded with a url, however I seem unable to be able to do this either with css or with jquery.

I have tried:

```
iframe html body {text-align:center}
$('iframe html body').css('text-align','center');
```

And neither appears to have any effect, I have also tried setting other attributes, but it has no effect on the contents at all.

Can this be done ??

## EDIT

OK, this appears to be a browser-related issue, I am actually trying to dynamically set the width and height of the iframe according to the contents loaded:

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
   $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
   $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
});
```

This works in safari and chrome, but has no effect at all in Firefox !

Comment: Is the iframe on your domain?

Comment: @SimonHartigan - Yes, same domain

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is on the same domain as the parent frame, you can use:

```
 $("iframe").contents();
```

Comment: I tried: $('#lb_ilf').contents().css('text-align','center'); (lb_ilf is the iframe id) - but that does not work either !

Comment: Does the src of the iFrame have the same domain as the outer page?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to achieve here?...  one thing you can do is give the iframe a class or id and define the specs you wan in the CSS. For example..

the HTML

```
<iframe id="some_name"></iframe>
```

the CSS

```
#some_name{
    text-align:center;
}
```

this should do what you need it to.

Comment: Thanks, but that was just an example, I want to be able to modify the attributes of any element with in iframe.